# How to split one RDD into multiple RDD and compare each other

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have master RDD like below

```
 [(u'google', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 22'),
 (u'google', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 22'),
 (u'google', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 23'),
 (u'google', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 24'),
 (u'google', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 25'),
 (u'Facebook', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 26'),
 (u'Facebook', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 27'),
 (u'google', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 28'),
 (u'google', u'00e293fd-80df-47c2-8762-b96c0b5e71c5', 'week 29'),
 (u'Facebook', u'0532e64a-7163-46a1-92ba-286b2a47bed5', 'week 30')]
```

I want to split them based on third column (which is by week index) for cohort analysis. One way I think of is converting RDD into data frame and partition based on week column and save it in text file and read it indivually and compare each other. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: What kind of comparisons you want to make ?

Comment: Lets say, 100 people are visited site in week 1 from google source. I want to see how many people from google source in week 1 are retained in week 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: If you want to work with different RDDs you can use the map transformation with return value key-value pair. And after than, with the lookup function, you can get the RDD of the key you wish. But for your result, i guess, it's not useful. You should create a dataframe and run group by SQL on this dataframe. Maybe after SQL you can divide by week column.

Answer (score 2):

I converted RDD into Dataframe and saved into partition by source with following piece of code

```
cohort_df = cohort.toDF(["source", "userId", "cohortId"])
cohort_df.write.partitionBy("source").csv("cohorts")
```

And, I split RDD into weeks by filtering by function like below

```
def week24(row):
    return "week24" == row[1]

week22_rdd, week23_rdd, week24_rdd, week25_rdd, week26_rdd = (cohortGroup_rdd.filter(f).map(lambda f: f[0]).distinct() for f in (week22, week23, week24, week25, week26))
```

and, used intersection of two RDD to find compare two RDDs and get common ids like below:

```
new_rdd = week22_rdd.intersection(week23_rdd)
```

This is best possible option I got to get me going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to help when this is all the information to work by, but you can always create a dataframe and the do group by or aggregate operations by the week. and the create SQL queries to compare. It will work in the example you gave in the comments.